# Getting a passport stamp while walking across a EU border

Tags: schengen, europe, switzerland, geneva, passport-stamps

So I have three different types of passport stamps from my EU travels. One for flying into Frankfurt, one for taking the Eurostar from London to Paris and one for taking a ferry from Dover to Calais.

This kinda makes me wonder...  what if I were to walk across the border? Would I get a walking passport stamp? Do they even have them?

Seems like a good place to do that would be Geneva. It'd be a bit of a walk but from the way it looks on Google Maps it looks like it's something that could be done in a day, there and back.

What if I walked to France and then took a taxi back? Could I do that and get a car passport stamp as well? Seems like taxi drivers doing that might not have passports large enough for all the stamps they could get..

Comment: I rollerbladed across the border from Liechtenstein to Austria a dozen years ago. I had to ask the surprised border guard for a "Stempel". I'm pretty sure that even though there wasn't a road but just a river and a very neglected and broken walking path that the passport stamp had a car logo on it. I'm not on the same passport now and that passport is at home while I'm travelling the world. So I can't check it right now...

Comment: Basel would have been a better place, actually — I think you could get a stamp by walking into the German station (Basel Bad). But now Switzerland is out: since it joined Schengen, there are no more border checks. Gibraltar should be an option.

Comment: I've also walked across Albania-Greece and Hungary Romania. Possibly some other ... time to check the map and the Wikipedia ...

Comment: @Gilles: You are no longer stopping at the border normally, but you can always stop and go talk to the border guard in case you have goods to declare, for example.

Comment: @Gilles There used to be a similar arrangement at Cornavin.

Comment: @Jonas but the border guards at Swiss land borders cannot stamp passports because nobody is entering or exiting the Schengen area when they cross a Swiss land border.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are only four types of passport stamps in the EU.

1. Road travel
2. Rail travel
3. Air travel
4. Ferry travel

It doesn't matter if you walk, take a bike, or travel by bus; if you cross from a road border, you will get a [road travel stamp.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Poland_korczowa_exit.jpg)

And also please note, since Switzerland is a member of Schengen zone, there are no border controls between Switzerland and France, therefore there isn't any stamp.

Comment: I crossed from Liechtenstein to Austria years before Switzerland and Liechtenstein joined Schengen. I forgot to mention that in my comment on the question.

Comment: It was odd biking across the Czech-Polish border and thinking how twenty years earlier, it would have been fortified. There wasn't any official, just a sign.

Comment: There often are border checks entering Switzerland by bus. That said, stamps aren't issued during those

Comment: @Crazydre I've similarly been stopped by customs officers entering and leaving Switzerland by car (I've not yet walked into or out of Switzerland at a controlled crossing unless you count Geneva's main train station, where I haven't been stopped).  As you surely know, these are customs checks, not immigration checks.  But even when there are temporary immigration controls on internal borders (in Switzerland or elsewhere), they would not stamp passports because the people crossing the border are neither entering nor leaving the Schengen area.

Comment: @phoog "As you surely know, these are customs checks, not immigration checks" They often are pure immigration checks, with only passports/visas/entry stamps being checked, and sometimes collected for scanning

Comment: @Crazydre I've lived in Geneva for the last year and nearly a half, and I've never seen anything other than customs checks except in the airport.

Comment: @phoog Fairs, I'm not too knowledgeable on Geneva. I lived in Zurich between 2014-2019 and, being the travel geek I am, regularly took Flixbus over the land borders, at the St Louis, Weil, Rheinfelden, Kreuzlingen and CHiasso motorway crossings. On about 50% of my entries into CH, passports and visas were checked (and possibly taken out for scanning), and only occasionally were goods part of the conversation. The Germans also commonly did this when entering DE (either Bundespolizei or Zoll - again mainly passport/visa checks regardless of which).

Comment: @Crazydre that was during the so-called migrant crisis, wasn't it?  I get the impression that the degree of scrutiny has been reduced considerably since then, though, to be fair, I've only been near the Swiss-German border a couple of times, and I haven't crossed it.

Comment: @phoog "that was during the so-called migrant crisis" Not only, but even in 2019, and also last month when I took FLixbus Munich-Zurich as a tourist. Last time passports/visas were checked, with non-EU/Schengen passports taken out for scanning. Not a word about goods.

Comment: @Crazydre interesting, thanks. I took a bus service from Geneva to Chamonix and back without our being stopped in either direction, so I can't say whether the officers would look at immigration documents when they do stop the bus. I once noticed several alert-looking officers at the municipal tram crossing from Thônex to Gaillard (towards Annemasse), but the trams were for some reason not crossing into France so I didn't see them checking account. It may be worthwhile to note that neither France nor Switzerland has 
an ID requirement as strict as the German _Passpflicht._

Comment: @phoog "It may be worthwhile to note that neither France nor Switzerland has an ID requirement as strict as the German Passpflicht." Switzerland does though; the SEM website has a list of accepted travel docs for EU/Schengen nationals, and refers to the EC Excel files for others, where each Schengen state lists the travel documents they accept. A Chinese bloke on the bus Munich-Zurich was sent back to Germany for only having his German residence permit and not his passport

Comment: @Crazydre that's for crossing the border.  I'm talking about a general requirement to carry identification documents.  A foreigner in Germany is supposed to have a passport or "Passersatz" at all times.  This is not the case in Switzerland.

Comment: @phoog Ah, misunderstood what you meant. Indeed no such obligation in Switzerland, though a good idea in border areas (speaking from experience)

Answer (score 2):

If each corresponding country has a travel agreement with one another, then stamps are unnecessary. With that said, however, it does not mean you cannot get them.

I travel to Ireland at least once a year on an Irish passport from the UK, and for the past two/three years, each time I ask for a stamp. I'm always met with either surprise or confusion from the assistant, which I believe is largely because they don't often use the stamps.

However I've never had my passport checked when coming into the UK from Ireland, which is pretty odd seeming that you get it very little the other way round. When I do, I'll be able to add a stamp to my growing collection :)

Neither the UK or Ireland falls under the Schengen Area, however they are a part of the Common Travel Area, which is basically the same  as the former, apart from the fact that it is limited to the Republic Of Ireland, the United Kingdom, the Isle of Man and the Channel Islands of Jersey & Guernsey.

I would love to have ones for the latter two. I've still not met anyone that has even set foot on them, lol.